# Can I use MONO to create a program that runs without the .NET framework being installed?

Tags: c#, windows, mono, embedded, windows-xp

I need to write something for a Windows XP embedded computer, which does not have .NET installed.

I already have written the program in .NET, so I'm wondering if there's a way to make it run without .NET?

Perhaps using MONO to create some all-in-one .exe?

Thanks for any thoughts / ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [mkbundle](http://mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Bundles) from Mono:

> The resulting executable is self contained and does not need the Mono
>   runtime installed to run.

Answer (score 0):

When running managed code - .NET/Mono assemblies, a framework is required to be installed. Depending on your dependencies, you may be able to run under mono without modification. Mono is compatible with Windows XP. Parts of .NET are not compatible with Mono such as WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `make it run without .NET` is an error concept. .net program must run at .net Environment. You can say `without .netframework`.

If you want to use .netframework, may these can help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/embedded/archive/2007/03/23/deploying-net-framework-3-0-desktop-distribution-package-on-windows-xp-embedded-sp2-runtime.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93e39489-2c61-439d-aa3f-865195fb79d7/net-framework-35-on-windows-xp-embedded?forum=embeddedwindowscomponents

Or you can setup monoruntime on this os